# Filling an input in any website and pressing enter

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small python script that will get a list of URLs (which are mostly just a search bar with some other elements), "write" something in the search bar and "press" enter.

My goal is to get to the next page, where all the search results are, and look at the new URL

The sites are different, so I can't just get the query parameter since I don't know it, and every site is different.

I was thinking about searching for the "input" part of the page (since the search bar is supposed to be the only input there), and send something to it. Then wait for the new URL.

Is that possible? Is there a smarter way?

- I'm trying to avoid using something else but python for now (selenium, etc..)
- I was searching every possible answer here and on the web, but nothing was possible so I was thinking about using the input part somehow...

Comment: Please add what you have developed so far.

Comment: I didn't. I couldn't find a way that I know/understand would work so there's nothing for me to show.  I know what (and how) to do what I want with the URL I get after the search, but what I'm trying to find is the way to get there. I don't have any more ideas, and obviously I can't just "guess" the new URL. I need to get there somehow. That's why I suggested maybe using the "input" part - but that's all I have for now.  Any Ideas?  Thank you

Comment: No, so far no ideas, because it is totally unclear what you are doing. Where do you get those urls from? Why do you need to use search bar, meaning browser? Why don't you use request library in python? What is the end goal of this?

Comment: @Alex Hello Alex, please see my new comment of rolf82 answer below. I hope it might help to explain what I'm trying to achieve a bit better. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without selenium and similar softwares, you'll have to understand what is actually happening when you click such a button.

I'll take an example on a famous site (hint: if you read this you'll know which site I mean). In the HTML source I can see that (truncated) piece of code:

```
 <form id="search" role="search" action=/search method="get" class="grid--cell fl-grow1 searchbar px12 js-searchbar " autocomplete="off">
            <div class="ps-relative">
                <input name="q"
                       type="text"
 ...
```

What it means is that when you submit the form, the browser would hit the URL `/search` (which here means `https://stackoverflow.com/search`), with a `get` request, wrapping all of the form's fields in the URL, after a `?`. If I searched for the term `python` it would lead to `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python`.

Note that according to their content, the parameters would need to be URL-encoded.

If the form contains more input fields, you'll have to wrap them too, separating them by `&` signs, in such a way: `param1=value1&param2=value2&...`

To sum up, searching only inputs won't be sufficient, you'll have to parse the forms.

Not knowing more about your data, I cannot elaborate, but I think you might be able to do something with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for the late reply (these COVID-19 days...)
To try and explain myself better - I want to use this site as an example: https://www.trustnav.com/en/
it's a simple page with a search bar. This search bar is the only input on the site. Now, I have a lot of this type and would like to find the "input" place, fill it and get the URL that it pass me to. In this example it's: https://search.trustnav.com/?q=test. 
I could not know in advance the query parameter or the "search" part that was added to the URL.  Does that help to understand my problem?  Thanks again

Comment: Yes I understand, and my answer is still valid: the `search.trustnav.com` part is given by the form's action attribute, and `q` is given by the name attribute of the input. With these informations you can build the URL

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. But what about something like this: http://start.iminent.com/en-US/search/ where there is no clear "action" or "get" request? Somehow the parameters a passed on, but I can't see how. Does it happen somehow "behind the scenes" via a server or something like that? When I try to search for "testme" I can see it was redirected to 
https://searchesnews.com/?a=gsp_iminent_00_00&q=testme and then 
https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=testme While the second must have redirected by the first - How did the first even occur?  Thank you for all the help so far

Comment: The URI in action can be relative, so a blank URI means that the request will be sent to the current URL. You have some explanations and examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form